# Conical resolution with torsion in the 1st homology group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

By a conical resolution I mean a resolution of singularities $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are endowed with an action of $\mathbb G_m$ (commuting with $\pi$) such that $Y$ is contracted to a single point by the action (everything is over $\mathbb C$).

Does anybody know a particular example when $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)$ has non-trivial $p$-torsion for some  (preferably small) prime $p$? Or may be it is obvious somehow that there is always no torsion?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $V$ be a smooth projective variety with nontrivial $p$-torsion (e.g. a Godeaux surface...). Let $Y$ be an affine cone over it, and $X$ the blow up of the vertex.

Comment: Oh, that's very simple and works - thanks a lot